# How to recover removed Docker images/containers after upgrading Docker Toolbox on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

I had installed Docker Toolbox [18.03.0-ce](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v18.03.0-ce) on Windows 7 64-bit and had many pulled images and built containers. After upgrading Docker Toolbox to [18.09.1](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v18.09.1), there are no images and containers in results of these listings, but my networks, volumes and used space in Boot2Docker are as the same as before:

```
$ docker images --all
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

$ docker container ls --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                                  DRIVER              SCOPE
446f56b6ddde        bridge                                bridge              local
7ec9271f1395        downloads_default                     bridge              local
d35c380fb35e        host                                  host                local
12beb20e048f        none                                  null                local
af4825df71cd        temp_default                          bridge              local
2b91271536ac        net1_default                          bridge              local
...

$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               c1a0b6eaea1d9bffa8ea1cff67fae47517f6cde6e7ff875c5264aba3a422a777
local               docker1_data
local               downloads_data
...
```

The old Docker Machine is also running as the same as before:

```
$ docker-machine.exe ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.06.1-ce
```

But the size of the virtual disk of Boot2Docker is still 15GB:

```
$ ls -lh /c/Users/hamid/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk
-rw-r--r-- 1 99777 1049089 15G Jan 20 11:41 /c/Users/hamid/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk
```

Also in the running Boot2Docker, `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs` has 10.6GB size:

```
root@default:/# du -d1 -h /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
20.0K   /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/builder
36.1M   /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/image
20.0K   /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/plugins
8.0K    /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp
270.7M  /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes
672.0K  /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containerd
72.0K   /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/buildkit
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/trust
136.0K  /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/network
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/runtimes
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/swarm
10.6G   /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
3.9M    /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers
10.9G   /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
```

The main large folder is `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` that has about 300 folders. It seems that old files are still there. Is there any way to recover images or containers back?